# Struts2 token session interceptor implementation challenge

Tags: struts2, token, interceptor

In my project i am trying to implement `TokenSession` interceptor of Struts2. I have done following entries :-

struts.xml:

```xml
<interceptor-stack name="tokenStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
</interceptor-stack>
```

struts-module1.xml:

```xml
<action name="Action1" class="Class1" method="method1">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenStack"/> 
    <result name="input">one.two.three</result>
```

and in JSP I have added this entry:

```xml
<s:token/>
```

After implementing this code I am getting below exception which i tried after changing autowire properties to name instead of type but that is not a feasible solution to me.:-

```xml
2016-01-18 15:23:29 ERROR SpringObjectFactory:[main]->->-> : Error building bean 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'textProvider': : Error creating bean with name 'abc'
```

Please help me with this problem provided i want to go with autowiring as 'type' only and struts version is 2.3 (Struts.xml).

Comment: Why do you change autowiring type? What is `abc` bean?

Comment: autowiring type is springs capability to create the bean searching either by type or by qualifier name...just to validate whether this is affecting i tried to make it name which removed the exception but i can not go fwd with it.

Comment: abc is class name  of bean.

Comment: *Error creating bean with name 'abc'* - There is some problem with this bean. Show your `abc` bean and how do you create it.

Comment: the whole code was working before I introduced this tokensessionstore interceptor.After introduction of this I started getting error so bean class should not be a problem

Comment: How do you create it? Does it have default constructor?

Comment: WHICH 2.3 version ? Show your jars. Also try upgrading every jar to the latest version (2.3.24.1)